# What is the C equivalent for reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c

What is the C equivalent for the `reinterpret_cast` from C++?

Comment: Note that the `(type)exression` equivalent of C can do much more than `reinterpret_cast` in C++ (well, after all, they are two different languages - so we can't expect much anyway). It can cast integer and floating point types into each other. Don't conclude from the answers that `(type)expression` in C++ is equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @litb This is an interesting comment. I checked the assembly code produced by VC2008 and it omits the same code. I am sure this is not enough, but I am really keen to know more on when does it differ?

Comment: Differing cases of compile time error and undefined behavior: `int a = reinterpret_cast<int>('a');` (compile error). `struct A { int a; }; struct B { int b; }; struct C : A, B { int c; }; int main() { C c; B &b = reinterpret_cast<B&>(c); b.b = 1; }` (undefined behavior: notice the difference when you change to `(B&)c`: if the B sub-object is stored at an offset `!= 0x0`, then `reinterpret_cast` is not required to care about any adjustments needed, while a C-style cast will do.

Comment: If you do eg float x; return (int)(x)+1; you should see it emit the proper fld/fistp sequence. If you're casting one pointer type to a different pointer type, there's actually no machine code necessary for that. A memory address is a memory address regardless of what it points at (on x86 anyway), so pointer "type" exists only in the mind of the compiler. The situation is different for inherited structures, where a C-style cast will deal with litb's situation by (eg) moving the pointer ahead from C's base to the locations of the B members it contains. But there's no inheritance in C anyway.

Comment: @Crashworks *A memory address is a memory address regardless of what it points at (on x86 anyway)*  Way late here, but [that's just not true, not even on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790550/c-undefined-behavior-strict-aliasing-rule-or-incorrect-alignment)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
int *foo;
float *bar;

// c++ style:
foo = reinterpret_cast< int * >(bar);

// c style:
foo = (int *)(bar);
```

Comment: Please also note litb's very good point in the comments to the original question.

Answer (score 8):

If you can take the address of the value, one way is to cast a pointer to it to a pointer to a different type, and then dereference the pointer.

For example, an float-to-int conversion:

```
int main()
{
  float f = 1.0f;

  printf ("f is %f\n", f);
  printf ("(int) f is %d\n", (int)f);
  printf ("f as an unsigned int:%x\n", *(unsigned int *)&f);
}
```

Output:

```
f is 1.000000
(int) f is 1
f as an unsigned int:3f800000
```

Note that this is probably not guaranteed to work by the C standard. You cannot use reinterpret_cast to cast from float to int anyway, but it would be similar for a type that was supported (for example, between different pointer types).

Let's confirm the output above makes sense, anyway.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32

The last answer in binary:

0011 1111 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

This is IEEE-754 floating point format: a sign bit of 0, followed by an 8-bit exponent (011 1111 1), followed by a 23 bit mantissa (all zeroes).

To interpret the exponent, subtract 127: 01111111b = 127, and 127 - 127 = 0. The exponent is 0.

To interpret the mantissa, write it after 1 followed by a decimal point: 1.00000000000000000000000 (23 zeroes). This is 1 in decimal.

Hence the value represented by hex 3f800000 is 1 * 2^0 = 1, as we expected.

Answer (score 4):

C-style casts just look like type names in parenthesis:

```
void *p = NULL;
int i = (int)p; // now i is most likely 0
```

Obviously there are better uses for casts than this, but that's the basic syntax.

Comment: Why 'most likely'? What would be the exception here?

Comment: NULL pointers are not guaranteed by the C standards to be represented as numeric 0. Even if they in practice are, on virtually all platforms.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't exist, because `reinterpret_cast` can not change [constness][3]. For example,

```
int main()
{
    const unsigned int d = 5;
    int *g=reinterpret_cast< int* >( &d );
    (void)g;
}
```

will produce the error:

> dk.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>      dk.cpp:5:41: error: reinterpret_cast from type 'const unsigned int*' to type 'int*' casts away qualifiers

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is quite old, but don't forget that doing things like :

```c
int a = 420;
int* b = &a;
printf("%f\n", *(double*)b);
```

is (unfortunately) most of the time undefined behavior (even though it may work and may potentially be ok in a lot of cases). Some cases when it's not undefined behavior is when you cast to `char*` or from `void*`, for example.
See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Strict_aliasing) and [GCC's manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fstrict-aliasing) (and even the [`memmove` page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove#Example)) for more informations.

To answer the question, unless the types are compatibles (as per the C standard, this is the only valid case where you can do the previously mentioned cast), a portable way to implement a `reinterpret_cast` could be to simply `memcpy` (or `memmove`) from TYPE_1 to TYPE_2 (or with `union` + type-punning).

For example with GCC's extensions:

```c
#define reinterpret_cast(TO, VAR) \
({                                \
    union                         \
    {                             \
        __typeof__((VAR)) source; \
        TO dest;                  \
    } u = { .source = (VAR) };    \
    (TO)u.dest;                   \
})
```

And we could even achieve a better syntax (something like `reinterpret_cast(uint32_t)(my_variable)`) with a military-grade preprocessor library such as [chaos-pp](https://github.com/rofl0r/chaos-pp) and its preprocessor lambdas, but this is probably not the subject.

You can try my solution [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:48,endLineNumber:18,positionColumn:48,positionLineNumber:18,selectionStartColumn:48,selectionStartLineNumber:18,startColumn:48,startLineNumber:18),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0A%23define+reinterpret_cast(TO,+VAR)+%5C%0A(%7B++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%5C%0A++++union+++++++++++++++++++++++++%5C%0A++++%7B+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%5C%0A++++++++__typeof__((VAR))+source%3B+%5C%0A++++++++TO+dest%3B++++++++++++++++++%5C%0A++++%7D+u+%3D+%7B+.source+%3D+(VAR)+%7D%3B++++%5C%0A++++(TO)(u.dest)%3B+++++++++++++++++%5C%0A%7D)%0A%0Aint+main(void)%0A%7B%0A++++const+int+a+%3D+0b01000100001000111001010010001011%3B+//+nearly+654.321+in+float%0A++++const+float+b+%3D+1.72998703212e-40%3B++++++++++++++++//+123456+in+int%0A++++printf(%22%25d%5Cn%22,+reinterpret_cast(int,+b))%3B%0A++++printf(%22%25f%5Cn%22,+reinterpret_cast(float,+a))%3B%0A%0A++++const+int*+a_ptr+%3D+%26a%3B%0A++++const+float*+b_ptr+%3D+%26b%3B%0A++++printf(%22%25d%5Cn%22,+reinterpret_cast(int,+*b_ptr))%3B%0A++++printf(%22%25f%5Cn%22,+reinterpret_cast(float,+*a_ptr))%3B+%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:44.15087028580766,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg132,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall+-Wextra%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:27.027280884083343,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27ARM+GCC+trunk%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:28.821848830109,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) btw.

Axel

Comment: Casting from `void *` will still be UB if the value isn't properly aligned for the new type - note that dereferencing the pointer is not necessary in that case.  And if `void *` points to an actual object of some type, and the new pointer is not of that type, any dereference will also violate strict aliasing and invoke UB.  It's still UB even if the pointer is "laundered" through `void *`.

Comment: But +1 for providing an answer where waaay too many other answers are rife with UB.

Answer (score 1):

A C-style cast is:

```
int* two = ...;
pointerToOne* one = (pointerToOne*)two;
```

Comment: shouldn't that '==' be a single '=''?

Comment: Both are valid statements, and both will compile only because of the cast. Of course, if you want something to happen other than compiling, you'd use '='

Answer (score 1):

What about a `REINTERPRET` operator for c:

```
#define REINTERPRET(new_type, var) ( * ( (new_type *)   & var ) )
```

I don't like to say "reinterpret_cast", because cast means conversion (in c),
while reinterpret means the opposite: no conversion.

Comment: Why should someone do this? It's misleading. Don't make your code unprovoked complexer.

Comment: @codemonkey To be able to have a struct (or other type) corresponding to more than one type, it can be useful (rarely) to create some construct using types. Say we have a struct concrete_type we always want to call a function on_copy onto when passing as an arg to some functions. You can create a type copy_type that has the same field types as concrete_type (thus same size in memory). All your functions will wait for a copy_type argument. on_copy will look like this proto : copy_type on_copy(concrete_type). In the body of the function, you simply reinterpret copy_type into concrete_type 1/2

Comment: @codemonkey 2/2 in case you passed concrete_type directly to functions, compiler will trigger an error. You can have copy_type have special field names as dont_use_me to be more explicit as well.

Comment: Cast doesn't necessarily mean conversion. When Kevin Costner was cast as Bat Man, he didn't literally become Bat Man; he was just interpreted as portraying Bat Man.

Comment: This code is a strict aliasing violation waiting to happen.  The only way this is not a strict aliasing violation is if `new_type` is `[[un]signed] char`.  Just about every other use, such as if `new_type` is `unsigned int` and `var` is of type `float`, will invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can freely cast pointer types in C as you would any other type.

To be complete:

```
void *foo;
some_custom_t *bar;
other_custom_t *baz;
/* Initialization... */
foo = (void *)bar;
bar = (some_custom_t *)baz;
baz = (other_custom_t *)foo;
```

Comment: You can freely cast any type, it just might not do what you hope it does, and might not be guaranteed to do anything at all.