# misaligned address access crash on linux wifi drivers on arc platform

Tags: c, linux, wifi, linux-device-driver

I am getting a crash on insmod of WIFI Marvell pcie drivers. 
i am running WIFI drivers on ARCH=arc OS=linux and little endian. 
crash back-trace says misaligned address access lead to crash. 
I have done some investigation and found the place of crash, below is the code snippet.

```
case NullPktPeriod_i:
        /** keep alive null data pkt interval in full power mode */
        psnmp_mib->oid = wlan_cpu_to_le16((t_u16)NullPktPeriod_i);
        if (cmd_action == HostCmd_ACT_GEN_SET) {
            psnmp_mib->query_type =
                wlan_cpu_to_le16(HostCmd_ACT_GEN_SET);
            psnmp_mib->buf_size = wlan_cpu_to_le16(sizeof(t_u32));
            ul_temp = *((t_u32 *)pdata_buf);
            *((t_u32 *)(psnmp_mib->value)) =
                wlan_cpu_to_le32((t_u32)ul_temp);
            cmd->size += sizeof(t_u32);
        }
        break;
```

crash is at line `*((t_u32 *)(psnmp_mib->value)) = wlan_cpu_to_le32((t_u32)ul_temp);` because `psnmp_mib->value` is unsigned char and typecast'd to `unsigned long int`. But the value we are assigning from `pdata_buf` is 1 byte value only `ul_temp = *((t_u32 *)pdata_buf);`.

The strange behavior is, if I initialize the `ul_temp (unsigned long int variable)` to zero (any value) and if I run, crash is not seen. but PCI command timeout happens for getting the get_hardware_spec command and kernel hangs.

I have no clue to fix this issue. Please provide some inputs to move further.

Blow is my crash logs,

```
[   29.920000] Path: (null)
[   29.930000] CPU: 0 PID: 1047 Comm: kworker/u3:1 Tainted: P           O 3.12.0 #103
[   29.930000] Workqueue: MOAL_WORK_QUEUE woal_main_work_queue [pcie8xxx]
[   29.940000] task: 9f0e02c0 ti: 9d192000 task.ti: 9d192000
[   29.940000]
[ECR   ]: 0x00230400 => Misaligned r/w from 0x9d451072
[   29.950000] [EFA   ]: 0x9d451072
[   29.950000] [BLINK ]: wlan_prepare_cmd+0x1be/0x478 [mlan]
[   29.950000] [ERET  ]: wlan_ops_sta_prepare_cmd+0x1fe0/0x37dc [mlan]
[   29.950000] [STAT32]: 0x00000a06 :          E2 E1
[   29.970000] BTA: 0x78571ccc   SP: 0x9d193c34  FP: 0x00000000
[   29.980000] LPS: 0x982de26c  LPE: 0x982de270 LPC: 0x00000000
[   29.980000] r00: 0x00000000  r01: 0x00000016 r02: 0x00000012
r03: 0x0000001e r04: 0x00000000 r05: 0x9d193cb4
r06: 0x9d451064 r07: 0x7857129c r08: 0xfffffffe
r09: 0x00000000 r10: 0x000004cf r11: 0x00000002
r12: 0x00000000
[   29.990000]
[   29.990000] Stack Trace:
```

Please help.

Comment: *"I have no clue to fix this issue..."* - You are probably going to have to take this to a kernel mailing list to get it fixed. [Linux Kernel Newbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/) is a great place because kernel devs hang there and are relatively gentle. The site also has a section on [Found a Bug](https://kernelnewbies.org/FoundBug). Your next step is probably to report it on the proper mailing list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. Just do the *right thing*. In general case, one would use [`memcpy`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-memcpy.html):

```
t_u32 value = wlan_cpu_to_le32((t_u32)ul_temp);
memcpy(psnmp_mib->value, &value, sizeof (t_u32));
```

As pointed out by [0andriy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2511795/0andriy), the `put_unaligned` could be used here:

```
put_unaligned(wlan_cpu_to_le32((t_u32)ul_temp), (t_u32*)psnmp_mib->value);
```

However this is very worrisome because the C standard does state that the [behaviour is undefined when](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2):

> Conversion between two pointer types produces a result that is incorrectly aligned ([6.3.2.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3)).

Thus even the mere *presence* of the cast `(t_u32*)` *can* lead to the compiler to "realize" that the pointer `psnmp_mib->value` is aligned to the alignment requirement of `t_u32` anyway.

---

Unaligned access - or even casting pointers to unaligned structures - has undefined behaviour even on platforms that ["supposedly" allow unaligned access "everywhere"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46790550/918959).

Comment: We have *get_unaligned()* and *put_unaligned()* helpers in the kernel. Better to use them and send patch upstream.

Comment: I read again the post and now even can say that *memcpy()* approach is overhead.

Comment: @0andriy I looked at the "put_unaligned" API... what is *very* worrisome is that it *too* (in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/unaligned-memory-access.txt) has undefined behaviour; `put_unaligned(value, (u32 *) data);` - the cast is invalid when `data` is unaligned.

Comment: @0andriy added anyway