# casting binary bytes (char*) to uint64_t*, is it safe?

Tags: c++, casting, memory-alignment

I am writing this C++ code that receives packages from remote server. Since the size of the package is not known in advance, the code first receives 8 bytes which tells the size of the whole package. Then it allocates a large enough buffer and receive the whole package into the buffer.

My question is with the casting from `const char*` to `uint64_t*` part: is it safe to cast the pointer and then read the content as `uint64_t`? What if the `buf` is not aligned to 8 bytes?

```
const char* buf;
RecvBytes(buf, sizeof(uint64_t));    // the first 8 bytes should tell us the size of the whole package
uint64_t pkg_size = *(uint64_t*)buf;  // is this safe??
const char* pkg = new char[pkg_size];
RecvBytes(pkg, pkg_size);
```

Comment: I assume that `buf` actually points to some valid allocated memory?

Comment: Why don't you just pass a pointer to a `uint64_t` variable, then it will be aligned properly.

Comment: Why `const char *` ???

Comment: You have not shown how and where `buf` is initialized. It affects greatly on result. If `buf` points to plain `char` array, you have worse problems than alignment issues.

Comment: If it's `const` you shouldn't be passing it to a function that modifies what it points to.

Comment: If I understand the question, you are concerned with whether what `RecvBytes(buf, sizeof(uint64_t));` puts in `buf` can be interpreted as a `uint64_t`. If that is your question, then it will depend on whether what is sent is sent in the correct byte-order (little/big endian) and whether `RecvBytes` messes that up in any way. Presuming there is a proper conversion from host to network before the bytes are sent, then you may need a network to host conversion on your end.

Comment: Regarding the comment from @Barmar, you say that both `buf` and `pkg` are pointing to memory that is constant and can't be modified. Attempting to write to "constant" memory leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in general, this should not be okay, but in one case, it *may* work, depending on the type of actual argument passed from the sender.

In other words, if the sender is sending a pointer to `uint64_t` type, only in that case, the code is acceptable.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.3

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the
>   resulting pointer is not correctly aligned68) for the referenced type, the behavior is
>   undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the
>   original pointer.

Comment: Would be better to quote from the C++ standard, not C.

Comment: @Barmar Oops, It was tagged C earlier.

Comment: It was tagged both, but it uses `new` so it's obviously C++.

Comment: @Barmar I agree sir, mea culpa, let me look up the reference.

Comment: As long as the address is properly aligned and there are actually 8 bytes at the address dereferencing it should be safe. There are plenty of architectures where dereferencing an unaligned pointer will cause a fault and even if it doesn't it will be a much slower access than a properly aligned value.

Comment: @Barmar sorry sir, I was looking up to § 4.10,  n4926, but did not find anything direct to support my statement. Can you help, what did I miss?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir [like x86](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46790815/918959)? The behaviour is undefined means that the behaviour is undefined, not that it should match your expectations of the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is only safe to cast a (`const`) `char *` to a type, if the pointer was obtained from that type and then casted to `char *`.

So here the bullet proof way is:

```
uint64_t pkg_size;
RecvBytes((const char *) &pkg_size, sizeof(uint64_t));
const char* pkg = new char[pkg_size];
RecvBytes(pkg, pkg_size);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am writing this C++ code that receives packages from remote server. Since the size of the package is not known in advance, the code first receives 8 bytes which tells the size of the whole package. Then it allocates a large enough buffer and receive the whole package into the buffer.

I think in the context of package exchange you should never allocate dynamically something or at least not without a max size. (And loop if necessary to compute all data)

I will in your case do something like this:

```
union {
  uint64_t size;
  char bytes[sizeof size];
} tmp;
RecvBytes(tmp.bytes, sizeof tmp.bytes);
if (tmp.size > SIZE_MAX) {
  // bad
}
size_t size = static_cast<size_t>(tmp.size); // or use tmp.size

char data[MAX]; // or use something more object
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i += MAX) {
  RecvBytes(data, min(size - i, MAX));
  // compute data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question is with the casting from const char* to uint64_t* part: is it safe to cast the pointer and then read the content as uint64_t?

In general, it is not safe and is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so you should be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108). For example, your code could crash on a [PowerPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC) machine, where pointers to `uint64_t` should be aligned to 8 bytes (otherwise, a `SIGBUS` or `SIGSEGV` could occur when dereferencing a misaligned pointer).

> What if the buf is not aligned to 8 bytes?

On [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) processors, you might use them: dereferencing a misaligned pointer is permitted, but is inefficient (so you should avoid doing that).

A dynamically allocated pointer (obtained by `malloc` or `::operator new`) is guaranteed to be well enough aligned, so the result of `new char[x]` can be safely cast to a `uint64_t*`

Comment: Could we stop spreading the [falsehoods about unaligned access on  x86](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46790815/918959)? It is actually **hurting** people. The program is written in C++ not x86 assembly.