# Brute-forcing find FILE* C

Tags: c, find, brute-force

I have been finding a way to brute-force finding a int64_t in a file in C.
I have written the following code.

```
int64_t readbyte = 0, totalreadbytes = 0;
int64_t totalfound = 0;
const int64_t magic = MAGIC_NUMBER;

char *buffer = (char *)malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
int64_t *offsets = (int64_t *)malloc(sizeof(int64_t) * (1 << 24));
if (buffer == NULL || offsets == NULL)
{
    return -3;
}

while ((readbyte = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, inptr)) > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= readbyte - 8; i++)
    {
        if (memcmp(buffer + i, &magic, sizeof(magic))==0)
        {
            offsets[totalfound++] = totalreadbytes + i;
        }
    }

    totalreadbytes += readbyte - 8;
    fseek(inptr, -8, SEEK_CUR);
}

// Do something to those offsets found

free(offsets);
free(buffer);
```

I have been wondering if there is a way better to find that int64_t, because my goal is to find them in a file as large as 60gigs and there maybe several hundred thousands of them in that file

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the fseek,

Comment: Notice that the code that you're using is *incorrect* - you must use `memcmp` instead of casting.

Comment: It is very unlikely that you will find a 64-bit number on a non-64-bit alignment. And on some platforms it's even invalid to access unaligned data like you do, and on other platforms (like x86 and probably x86-64) there's a performance penalty for accessing unaligned data.

Comment: @MichaelWalz cause that int64_t maybe have some part at last of data and some on the beginning of next data read

Comment: If you don't read the whole file how can you find it? Well -- if it's working you may want to ask on [codereview.se], but (**important**, to avoid downvotes) read their help center before asking.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I have been checking till readbyte-8, so it will avoid checking beyond the data

Comment: There are 2 errors: strict aliasing (which might not be an issue here) and alignment. `memcmp` is the correct way to do - you'll load the `MAGIC_NUMBER` into a `const int64_t` local variable, then `memcmp(buffer + i, magic, sizeof magic) == 0`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I get the secone one but I couldn't understand strict aliasing and alignment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790550/c-undefined-behavior-strict-aliasing-rule-or-incorrect-alignment?rq=1

Comment: Your particular code might just work fine with any current or future compiler but it is not to say that in general case such a cast would be OK.

Comment: Have you considered `mmap`?

Comment: What is your [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format)? You should document it precisely. Maybe you could use [grep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backing up and re-reading data is going to slow things down quite a bit.

Building on @melpomene comment, here's a very simple way to do it with `mmap()`:

```
uint64_t needle;

struct stat sb;
int fd = open( filename, O_RDONLY );
fstat( fd, &sb );

unsigned char *haystack = mmap( NULL, sb.st_size,
    PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0 );

close( fd );

off_t bytesToSearch = sb.st_size - sizeof( needle );

// <= so the last bytes get searched
for ( off_t ii = 0; ii <= bytesToSearch; ii++ )
{
    if ( 0 == memcmp( haystack + ii, &needle, sizeof( needle ) ) )
    {
         // found it!
    }
}
```

Error checking and proper headers omitted for clarity.

There are a lot of ways to improve the performance of that.  This IO pattern is the **worst** possible use of `mmap()` with regards to performance - read every byte in the file just once, then throw the mappings away.  Because mapping a file isn't all that fast in the first place, and it impacts the entire machine.

It'd probably be a *lot* faster to just use `open()` and `read()` with direct IO in large page-sized chunks into page-aligned memory, especially if the file is a significant fraction of the system's RAM.  But that would make the code much more complex, as the comparisons would have to span buffers - it's almost certainly much faster to use two buffers and copy a few bytes out to search across a break between buffers than it is to back up and do a non-aligned read.