# 9 Digit Addresses in Hexadecimal System in MacOS

Tags: c, macos, memory, memory-address, digits

I am practicing on C programming language. I had Win 10 systems and I was practicing on it and I always get addresses which are multiples of 2. Know, I am practicing on Macbook Pro M3 and I get 9 digit addresses. So, nine is odd.

Also, here is the code and result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int m = 10, n, o, *z;

    z = &m;

    printf("z stores the address of m = %p\n", z);
    printf("*z stores the value of m = %d\n", *z);
    printf("&m is the address of m = %p\n", &m);
    printf("&n stores the address of n = %p\n", &n);
    printf("&o stores the address of o = %p\n", &o);
    printf("&z stores the address of z = %p\n", &z);

    return 0;
}
```

```
z stores the address of m = 0x16fa13228
*z stores the value of m = 10
&m is the address of m = 0x16fa13228
&n stores the address of n = 0x16fa13224
&o stores the address of o = 0x16fa13220
&z stores the address of z = 0x16fa13218
```

I researched about it however I couldn't get good answers. Here what I found:

[why the value of address in c s always even?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380087/why-the-value-of-address-in-c-s-always-even)

[Strange address of a C variable in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51305965/strange-address-of-a-c-variable-in-mac-os-x)

I was expecting to see addresses in even digits.

Comment: I think you'll need to clarify your question.  I don't see anything odd with the output you're seeing.

Comment: Re “I was expecting to see addresses in multiple digits”: Nine digits is multiple digits. Re “Win 10…  I always get addresses which are multiples of 2”: Do you mean the number of digits is a multiple of two? There is no particular reason the number of hexadecimal digits in an address should be a multiple of two. We often represent addresses using eight-bit bytes, and eight bits is equivalent to two hexadecimal digits, so, if the hexadecimal digit is not zero, there will be an even number of digits (e.g., eight for 32 bits, 16 for 64). But the leading digit can be zero and leave an odd number.

Comment: To be pedantic, for hexadecimal they're called *hexits*. But there is nothing strange about a 9-hexit number. You can pad it with 0s on the left to any width you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [C23 draft](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3220.pdf):

7.23.6.1 The `fprintf` function

> 8. The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> - `p` The argument shall be a pointer to void or a pointer to a character type. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an **implementation-defined** manner.

That means that different implementations may produce different output, even if the actual pointer values would happen to be the same.

> I was expecting to see addresses in even digits.

I'm assuming this means that you expected to see an even number of digits. Typically, no more than the significant non-zero digits will be printed so if you get 9 digits on your Mac, that's just an effect of that. A 32 bit address like `0x00000FFF` will often be printed as just `0xFFF`.

---

If you want the same format on all platforms and implementations, you could cast the pointer to `uintptr_t` and print that instead.

Example:

```c
#include <inttypes.h> // PRIxPTR
#include <stdint.h>   // uintptr_t
//...
printf("&n stores the address of n = 0x%016" PRIxPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)&n);
```

Possible output:

```
&n stores the address of n = 0x000000016fa13224
```

Comment: This seems silly - why would you expect the pointers to be the same? They're different architectures, and different operating systems.

Comment: @NickODell I'm not expecting the pointers to be the same. I said, _even if_ they happened to be the same, different implementations may present them differently. Is that misunderstanding the part that attracts downvotes?

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree that this is implementation-defined. It just doesn't seem relevant to the question at hand. If OP had asked for how to get pointers to print out with an even number of digits, I would be totally on board with this answer. But the question here seems conceptual.

Comment: @NickODell Ok, thanks. I added added a note to more clearly address what I think OP's query is about.

Comment: I think the OP’s question is more likely why the address has the value it has, i.e. a “nine-digit address” like 0x16fa13224 rather than an eight-digit address like 0xff003224 or a sixteen-digit address like 0x800000006fa13224 like the OP has seen on another system than why the address is formatted in a particular way. And the answer is the program loader is designed to arrange memory differently on the different systems, nothing to do with formatting addresses.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  Oh, it's not how I interpreted it, but yes, it's certainly possible that that's what OP is really asking about. I've asked for clarification about the last part in the question (which confuses me a bit).

Answer (score 0):

> I had Win 10 systems and I was practicing on it and I always get
> addresses which are multiples of 2

> Know, I am practicing on Macbook Pro M3 and I get 9 digit addresses.

It does not depend on a number of digits only the the value of that number.

Example:  `0x16fa13228` is `6167802408` in decimal. This number is dividable by 2.