# How to modify more than 1 Byte in an array?

Tags: c

What I am trying:

```
BYTE test[] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
*(test+1) = 0xFFFF;
```

What I get:

```
00000000 11111111 00000000 00000000
```

What I expect or want to achieve:

```
00000000 11111111 11111111 00000000
```

Background:
In one part of my program I need to insert a WORD into a part of an array.
Yes, normally I could just do

```
*(test+1) = 0xFF;
*(test+2) = 0xFF;
```

but I wonder if there is a possibility to do this as a one-liner like in the first example. Memcpy is no option here since I would need to allocate space for a second array.

Comment: The short answer is 'no'.  The long answer involves type-punning through unions.  Unless, that is, you really are just trying to set the values as Alok Singhal showed in his answer using memset.

Comment: @IłyaBursov That breaks strict aliasing and is undefined behavior.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons isn't byte exception from this rule?

Comment: I was about to say 'no' unless you play with types and such, but since @ChristianGibbons already said it, so I'm not gonna say it now :D

Comment: "Memcpy is no option here since I would need to allocate space for a second array." This makes little sense. First, paraneters to `memcpy` need not be arrays, an address of a single integer will do. Second, if you for some reason do need a second array (you don't but let's pretend), it would be of whoppin' two elements. Allocating such an array on the stack is not a problem.

Comment: @IłyaBursov It is a one-way street (and technically it's character types, so `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` specifically).  Character-types can alias any other type, but not the other way around.

Comment: `memset` is your friend but … why? why not write the code simple and easy to understand - like: `test[1]=0xff; test[2]=0xff;` done... easy to write - easy to understand. If you need to set many elements then `memset` is good. Alternatively make a `for`-loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your options are

1. ```
   test[1] = 0xFF;
   test[2] = 0xFF;
   ```
2. ```
   memset(test + 1, 0xFF, 2);
   ```
3. ```
   const char bytes[2] = {0xFF, 0xFF};
   memcpy(test + 1, bytes, 2);
   ```
4. ```
   uint16_t value = 0xFFFF;     // beware of byte order
   memcpy(test + 1, &value, 2);
   ```
5. ```
   memcpy(test + 1, (const unsigned char []){0xFF, 0xFF}, 2));
   ```
6. or any other code that addresses the individual bytes separately.

---

What is *not* an option is:

```
*(uint16_t)&test[1] = 0xFFFF;
```

The reason is simple: it breaks two rules in C: strict aliasing *and* alignment. What is worse is that you *can* get away with this in *this* part of code, but [dereferencing unaligned `uint16_t` pointers is never safe, even on x86-64 that supposedly supports unaligned accesses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790550/c-undefined-behavior-strict-aliasing-rule-or-incorrect-alignment)

Answer (score 5):

For this case, `memset(test+1, 0xFF, 2)` should work.

Comment: Excellent! Good compilers will generate a single instruction on x86 targets, as can be seen on https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WmgIjo . Unaligned writes are OK on these targets for most OSes.

Answer (score -1):

```
#define modify(dest,src,pos)    do { unsigned char *tmp =(void *)&dest; memcpy(tmp + pos,&src, sizeof(src));}while(0)

void *modify1(void *dest, void *src, size_t pos, size_t len)
{
    unsigned char *tmp = dest;
    memcpy(tmp + pos, src, len);
    return tmp + pos;
}
```

examples:

```
char x[10];
short y = 0xffff;
modify(x,y,3);

or modify1(x,&y, 3, sizeof(y));
```

Note that the macro one will not work in all circumstances.

Answer (score -2):

The following code is a generic solution that let you write a value of 2 Bytes (16 bits) into successive cells of an array :

```c
uint16 data = 0xFFFF;

BYTE test[] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
*(test+1) = data & 0xFF;
*(test+2) = data >> 8;
```

The result will be:

```
00000000 11111111 11111111 00000000
```

So just change the value of `data`.

Comment: That just seems like a more complicated version of OPs original code (adding unnecessary bitwise operations)

Comment: I assumed that the value to be written may change. This is a more generic solution.

Comment: Why create a `uint16` if your only intent is to access its individual constituent bytes?

Comment: The `uint16 data` is just an example of 2 Bytes data that could be written. So we can even wrap it into a function.