# How to convert a char pointer array into a int pointer array in C

Tags: c, arrays, endianness

I have an 8 byte char pointer that has 2 integers stored inside it. how do I store it in a int array pointer so that the int array has the 1st integer is in `array[0]` and the 2nd integer is in `array[1]`.

The code I made so far:

```
char * wirte_buff= (char*) malloc(8*sizeof(char*));
int i, j;
i =  16;
j = 18;

/*separates integer i and integer j into 4-bytes each*/ 
for(n=0; n<=3; n++){
  wirte_buff[n] = (i >> 8*(3-n)) & 0xFF;
  wirte_buff[4+n] = (j >> 8*(3-n)) & 0xFF; 
}

int* intArray = (int*) wirte_buff; //puts char pointer to 
printf("intArray[0] value is %d \n", intArray[0]);
printf("intArray[1] value is %d \n", intArray[1]);
```

When I did this it the expected result was 16 and 18, but I unexpectedly got 268435456 and 301989888.

Comment: It might be of value to you that `16` is `0x10` and `0x10000000` is equal to `268435456`. Similar `18` is `0x12` in hex, and `0x12000000` is `301989888` in base 10.

Comment: You can debug the code and see what's happening in memory at the address of `write_buff`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `int* intArray = (int*) wirte_buff; //puts char pointer to ` is [a strict aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and undefined behavior.   You can not safely refer to a `char` array as an `int` unless the memory referred to is actually an `int` variable. In this case, it's not. Bad code like this tends to get taught by a lot of people who should know better because x86 systems are very forgiving with misaligned accesses and usually let you get away with it.

Comment: (cont) [But not always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790550/c-undefined-behavior-strict-aliasing-rule-or-incorrect-alignment).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are aware of the [strict aliasing rule violation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/11336762), your code would generate the result you expect in a *big endian* architecture, in which the four bytes composing an integer are stored starting from the most significant byte:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| byte3 (bit 24:31) | byte2 (bit 16:23) | byte1 (bit 8:15) | byte0 (bit 0:7) |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But you are apparently running your code in a ***little endian*** architecture machine:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| byte0 (bit 0:7) | byte1 (bit 8:15) | byte2 (bit 16:23) | byte3 (bit 24:31) |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, in order to displace your integer in the char array, you need that:

1. The byte 0 of `i`, that is `i >> (8 * 0)`, is at index 0 of `wirte_buff` array
2. The byte 1 of `i`, that is `i >> (8 * 1)`, is at index 1 of `wirte_buff` array
3. The byte 2 of `i`, that is `i >> (8 * 2)`, is at index 2 of `wirte_buff` array
4. The byte 3 of `i`, that is `i >> (8 * 3)`, is at index 3 of `wirte_buff` array

This translates in

```
wirte_buff[n] = (i >> 8*(n)) & 0xFF;
```

and the same, of course, for `j`:

```
wirte_buff[4+n] = (j >> 8*(n)) & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong in many ways.

- `char * wirte_buff= (char*) malloc(8*sizeof(char*));` allocates 8 `char*` and no data. You don't assign these pointers anywhere, so they remain uninitialized.
- `i >> ...` etc performs bitwise operations on a signed type, which is always wrong. If the value is negative, you end up with implementation-defined results.
- Should you convert the `int` value into `char`, then `char` has implementation-defined signedness so you don't know if you end up with a negative value or possibly an overflow/underflow.
- Should you avoid that as well, you can't read a `char` back through another type with `(int*) wirte_buff;` ... `intArray[0]` because these are not compatible types. You might read misaligned data. You will also violate strict pointer aliasing, see [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

There is no expected behavior of the posted code and I doubt you can salvage it. You will have to re-write this from scratch and especially avoid all the fishy conversions.