# structure after "packed" still bigger than it should be

Tags: c, linux, gcc, structure, memory-alignment

**Problem is solved. Mistake was not to rethink about given datatypes...**
The size of following structure is bigger than it should be:

```
typedef unsigned char    byte;
typedef unsigned short   word;
typedef unsigned long    dword;

struct Y
{
 short      h;
 byte       i;       
}
#if defined (__GNUC__)
    __attribute__((__packed__));
#endif

struct X
{
   short    a;
   byte     b;
   byte     c;
   word     d;
   dword    e;
   byte     f;
   byte     g;
   word     h;
   short    i;
   struct Y G[8];
}
#if defined (__GNUC__)
    __attribute__((__packed__));
#endif

printf("size of X should be 40 but is %i", sizeof(struct X));
```

Output:

```
size of X should be 40 but is 44
```

I need this structure with a size of 40 Bytes (sum of all elements), 44 is the lowest I can reach. Compiler is GCC C, `byte` is `unsigned char`, `word` is `unsigned short` and `dword` is `unsigned long`. `sizeof(Y)` is 3. What is the problem here?

Comment: What are `byte`, `word` and `dword`? Those are not standard types. Also, you are printing "size of X should be", but you output the size of `Y` instead. Finally, what is `struct J`? Please, ensure your code is a **[mre]**.

Comment: byte is unsigned char, word is unsigned short and dword is unsigned long

Comment: Well, add that to the code in the question then! Also, we still don't know what `struct J` is. Did you mean `struct Y`? I also really doubt `sizeof(Y)` is 44.

Comment: Instead of implementation dependant types like `short` etc I suggest to use types from `stdint.h`, e.g. `int16_t` etc. You can use `offsetof` and `sizeof` for individual structure fields to check what's different from your expectations.

Comment: What is `sizeof(dword)` (or `sizeof(unsigned long)`) on this system? If it is 8 rather than the 4 you expect, then that would account for the difference between 40 and 44 bytes.

Comment: i did not write this struct but i have to work with it without changing it. Without the dword variable in X i get the right size

Comment: Why not inspect the `sizeof`s and `offsetof`s of the individual members? At the moment, most of the energy in trying to answer is wasted by guessing the types and their sizes.

Comment: This is also relevant: [**Is gcc's __attribute__((packed)) / #pragma pack unsafe?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568432/is-gccs-attribute-packed-pragma-pack-unsafe)  The answer is "Yes".  There are even examples of misaligned access failure on x84 systems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790550/c-undefined-behavior-strict-aliasing-rule-or-incorrect-alignment and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510783/why-does-unaligned-access-to-mmaped-memory-sometimes-segfault-on-amd64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types you define are flawed. Ideally I'd suppose that `dword` should be double the size of `word`, but you are defining the two as:

```c
typedef unsigned short   word;  
typedef unsigned long    dword;
```

And it turns out that on your platform `sizeof(unsigned short)` is `2`, while `sizeof(unsigned long)` is `8`, *not* `4`.

You should really avoid such definitions and use the standard types provided in `stdint.h`:

```
byte  -> uint8_t
short -> uint16_t
word  -> uint16_t
dword -> uint32_t
```

Finally, your structure declaration is invalid if the macro `__GNUC__` is not defined, because you would be missing the final semicolon (`;`). You can change it to something like this:

```c
#if defined (__GNUC__)
__attribute__((__packed__))
#endif
struct Y
{
 uint16_t h;
 uint8_t  i;       
};
```