# Passing char uninitialiezed pointer address and allocation and extraction of member variables

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am passing `char *` pointer from main to a function `abc` which is uninitialized pointer. And I am composing a network packet so like what allocated in the function I want it to be the representation of a packet. So This is my passing of uninitialized pointer in function call inside `main`

```
            char *pay;
            abc(&pay);
```

in the function I have as signature of a function like following

```
            void abc(char **c)
```

this is the full function

```
        void abc(char **c)
        {
            *c=(char *) malloc(sizeof(struct ethhdr)+sizeof(struct iphdr)+sizeof(struct tcphdr)+1000/*1000=payload*/);
            struct ethhdr *eth=(struct ethhdr *)&*c;
            struct iphdr *ip=(struct iphdr *)(&*eth+sizeof(struct ethhdr));
            struct tcphdr *tcp=(struct tcphdr *)(&*ip+sizeof(struct iphdr));
            //populate eth
            //...
            //populate ip
            //...
            //populate tcp
            tcp->source=80;
            printf("%d\n",tcp->source);
            int *x=(int *)*c;
            //x=10;

        }
```

I like to know how can I cast second line in `abc` function
I am doing like this

```
        struct ethhdr *eth=(struct ethhdr *)&*c;
```

> second line inside `abc` function.

But at line containing this instruction `tcp->source=80;` its causing segFault.

So my question is how can I cast the `c` double pointer in function and to assign it to`struct ethhdr *`,`struct iphd *` and `struct tcphdr *` pointers

And how to assign the values to members of `struct ethhdr` , `struct iphdr` and `struct tcphdr`

I tried like

> tcp->source=80;

But causing segFault

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.

The first is the use of both the address-of and dereference operators in:

```
struct ethhdr *eth=(struct ethhdr *)&*c;
```

The expression `&*c` is the same as plain `c`, which isn't correct. You need `*c` here:

```
struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *) *c;
```

You have similar problem with the other pointers (e.g. `&*eth`) but there it doesn't cause any problems because of this. Use just plain `eth` (for example).

---

The second problem is two-fold, and is all the other assignments. First of all the pointers you use are not byte pointers which means casting to another structure pointer will break *strict aliasing*.

Secondly you have to remember that for any pointer or array `p` and index/offset `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is exactly equal to `p[i]`. For an expression like `eth+sizeof(struct ethhdr)` that means it's the same as `&)eth[sizeof(struct ethhdr)])`. Which is clearly wrong (`eth` could be seen as an array of one element, not an array of at least `sizeof(struct ethaddr) + 1` elements.

To fix both these problems, strict aliasing and the offsets, you need to use the original byte-pointer `*c` and add the offsets in bytes to that:

```
struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr *) (*c + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
struct tcphdr *tcp = (struct tcphdr *) (*c + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr));
```

---

From the above it should now be relatively easy to figure out how to get a pointer to the payload data, because it's not plain `*c` as used in your code.

Comment: `First of all the pointers you use are not byte pointers which means casting to another structure pointer will break strict aliasing.` what do u mean by aliasing does this statement  `struct ethhdr *eth=(struct ethhdr *)*c` ; is correct` but this `struct iphdr *ip=(struct iphdr *)(&*eth+sizeof(struct ethhdr));` Is NOT correct. what I understood is that `struct iphdr *` is not byte pointer because its size is different and not `1 byte`

Comment: @666 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790550/c-undefined-behavior-strict-aliasing-rule-or-incorrect-alignment this is related.