# Writing structures

Tags: c, pointers, struct, casting

I'm learning C and currently, structures. I'm looking at the following code:

```
struct client {
    char name[20];
    int key;
    int index;
};

struct client Client[100]; 

int function(void *ClientDetail) {
    struct client *clientDetail = (struct client*) ClientDetail; // what is this line doing?
}
```

could you please explaint the importance of the commented line?

Thanks

Comment: Importance? Every character is important, except the comments.

Comment: Where did you find this code?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Sorry, I tried to post a snippet of code and I made a mistake. Fixed it.

Comment: Note that if the memory pointed to by the `ClientDetail` void pointer isn't actually a `struct client` structure, the code invokes undefined behavior because it violates the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).  It can also invoke undefined behavior because it can violate any alignment restrictions on the system it's running on.  Anyone who tells you, "But it works" [left out the "until it doesn't" part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790550/c-undefined-behavior-strict-aliasing-rule-or-incorrect-alignment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
struct client *clientDetail = (struct client*) ClientDetail;
```

reinterprets the address stored in the pointer `ClientDetail` that has the type `void *` due to this declaration

```
int function(void *ClientDetail) {
```

as an address to an object of the type `struct client`.

Now using the pointer `clientDetail` you can access the addressed memory as if there is an object of the type `struct client`.

Pay attention to that it is a bad idea to use these identifiers `ClientDetail` and `clientDetail` that differ only in the case of the first letter.

Comment: Also a good idea to avoid the use of void pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The function `function` takes an argument of type `void*` and assigns it to a local variable. The type cast `(struct client*)` is unnecessary and has no effect, as the data type `void*` can be implicitly converted to any pointer type. Note that this only applies to the programming language C, not C++.

In the posted code, the function argument and the local variable have a very similar name. However, due to C being case-sensitive, the names are considered different by the compiler.